# How to fetch data from firebase realtime database in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building an app in Flutter in which I have data stored in the Firebase Realtime Database. I want to fetch those data in my app.

Now, Because of breaking changes made few months ago I'm unable to find new articles or video which might help but all I find are old ones so if anyone here can help me?

variable for the list

```
final dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("workshops");
```

now for showing the data I'm trying like this

```
return FutureBuilder(
      future: dbRef.once(),
      builder: (context,AsyncSnapshot<DataSnapshot> snapshot){
        if(snapshot.hasData){
          workshopList.clear();
          Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = snapshot.data.value;
          values.forEach((key,values){
            workshopList.add(values);
          });
        }
        return ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: workshopList.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index){
            return Card(
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Text("name "+ workshopList[index].workshopName)
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      }
      
    );
```

Comment: Wat are u getting

Comment: There is plenty of documentation online that shows you how to use the updated firebase rtdb with flutter. You're also doing a lot of things wrong here. Your FutureBuilder gets called every time the widget rebuilds instead of getting called only once. Your ListView.builder is not building each item lazily because shrinkWrap is true. Building lazily means that you're only building the widget once it has to show up in the screen. With shrinkWrap, you are building everything all at once. Remove shrinkWrap and wrap the Listview with expanded

Comment: The documentation here is up to date with any changes: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview

Comment: @Uni thanks for your reply, I will work on that and thank you everyone and I know what was wrong with my code which I will accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For declaring list I was doing like this

```
List<Workshop> worskshopList = [];
```

but what worked for me was

```
List<Map<dynamic,dynamic>> workshopList = [];
```

And now for showing the data I am using

> workshopList[index].workshopName

now problem with this is that I am not referencing database's workshopname but my model class' workshop name so I am getting nowhere.

now what worked for me was

> workshopList[index]["workshopname"]

now from the old list I can't use like list[index][""] it will give an error like   "[]" is not defined for the list.